# Finding letters in a column and extracting a row containing a sepecific letter

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, contains

[image]

I'm trying to editing data with Pandas.

1. I want to find letters in 'File1' by searching for letters in a column.
2. I want to find the row that contains the letters while searching for the letters found in 'File 1' in 'File 2'.

is there a way I can do in this situation?

Comment: File 1 and File 2 are dataframe format?

Comment: You'll get better help if you include File 1 and File 2 in text to your question

Comment: yeah! both of them are dataframe format.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
df2['new'] = df2['col'].str.findall('|'.join(df1['col'].tolist()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'file1' : ['JVD', 'WFX', 'DGC', 'HHD', 'WEV', 'IUV',
                               'MDE']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'file2' : ['123JVD42', '123WFX3', '234WEV', '231sD2']})

searchfor = list(df1['file1'])
df2[df2['file2'].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor))]
```